# How to `h5repack` an H5 dataset that is grouped

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to run the `hdf5` command line tool `h5repack` to change the compression of an H5 file. I've succeeded at this on variants of the H5 file that had no grouping, but now I have an H5 file with grouping. I don't know how to reference the table through the group structure.

My table is named `raw` and I've tried this unsuccessfully:

```
h5repack --filter raw:NONE -i input.h5 -o output.h5
Error occurred while repacking
```

On older version of my H5 file where no grouping structure existed that worked fine.

To reference my new H5 file in `h5py` I use the following format which shows the grouping hierarchy:

```
import h5py

f = h5py.File('myfile.h5')
f['recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw']
```

[Reading the `h5repack` docs here](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/h5repack), they don't explain how to reference the `raw` dataset when it's grouped. I've guessed at the format without success, here's one example guess:

```
h5repack --filter=recordings.rec0000.well0000.groups.routed.raw:NONE -i in.h5 -o out.h5
Error occurred while repacking
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the complete path to the `raw` dataset with slashes ('/'), like this:
(I added the -v option to get Verbose output.)

```
h5repack -v -f /recordings/rec0000/well0000/groups/routed/raw:NONE input.h5 output.h5
```

-OR-

```
h5repack -v -i input.h5 -o output.h5 -f /recordings/rec0000/well0000/groups/routed/raw:NONE
```